# Python: Reading csv file and writing it to list-(error)-[need suggestion]

Tags: python, csv

I opened Excel, added values 4 values `[say eng,hin,pol,rus]` in the first row of it, saved it in .csv file

The code:

```
import csv
list1=['1','2','c']
print 'list1 is',list1
list2[]
with open('abc.csv','rb') as f:
                reader=csv.reader(f)
                for row in reader:
                list2.append(row)
print 'Values in list2 are:',list2
```

The output i'm getting is:

```
list1 is['1','2','c']
Values in list2 are:[['eng'],['hin'],['pol'],['rus']]
```

The values are getting stored in the list as `['eng'],['hin']` ... I want it to get saved in `list2` as `['eng','hin',pol','rus']`.

Any possible solution and explanation as to why is it happening? Not sure what exactly it does but I got the same result using `reader=csv.reader(f,delimiter=';')`

I want to achieve it without using `xlrd`, `xlwt` and other libraries, any suggestions?

Comment: it's unclear what is the the problem

Comment: The issue here is that, the values are getting stored in list2 as [['eng'],['hin'],['pol'],['rus']], while i want it as  ['eng','hin',pol','rus'].

Comment: I'd suggest you spell the instance methods correctly and use appropriate indentation. Also, if you just want the first element of a list `l`, it's `l[0]`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i want to know why values in list2 are getting stored as ['eng'], ['pol']... any idea?

Comment: Because you're appending single-element lists to a list. Each `row` in a `csv.reader` is a list. That's why they look like lists.

Comment: @jonrsharpe wow that makes sense.. thnx
bt any possible solution for it... i want them as list element e.g as ['eng','hin','pol']

Comment: what does your `.csv` file look like in raw?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I got the solution. list2.extend() is to used in place of list2.append()

Comment: This still doesn't tell us why it's reading one element at a time while it should read all 4 at once. You're likely to run into another problem as soon as you add something else into the file.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev i'm new to programming.. in learning phase. I hope the below explanation helps..
Based on my understanding and suggesitons by diff users, here it is taking each cell element of the csv as a separate list. So append is simply adding the list into another list.

Comment: Whatever. If you're satisfied with the solution, fine. It's your question, after all. I'll still downvote it as i'm free to do since it really doesn't address the real issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try extend instead of append.  That will add the various lists to the end of your list, rather than as sub-lists within it.

Literally:

```
... 
list2.extend(row) 
...
```